# Pick A DIV Content Of Same Page And Show It On Same Page In PHP

Tags: php, html, css, regex, curl

I have a web-page in which there is some text like `<h1 class="page-title">Some Text</h1>` but I hide it through `.page-title{display:none;}` as I don't want to show it there. Now I want to show the same **Some Text** in another DIV of same web-page. This **Some Text** is dynamic but `<h1>` tag and `class="page-title"` is same on every page like `<h1 class="page-title">...</h1>`. I only want to show it through PHP as I can do it via JavaScript/JQuery.

I Googled many time but every time I am getting the code of picking the DIV content from other page but here I want to pick and show on the same page. Keep in mine the this **Some Text** is also generated by PHP so I think we need to post it again after this to allow him to load first then pick from there but I want to show it before **Some Text** on web-page. How to do this?

Comment: So you can use javascript or you cant?

Comment: @InyaProduction No. Just need PHP codes because I don't want to show it on visitor end...

Comment: You cant execute PHP Script after the page has been loaded at the users browser, do you have all the php script in on variable at php? Then it could be possible to read the value before sending it to the user. Else there is only javascript possible

Comment: @InyaProduction The reason why I can't edit `<h1 class="page-title">Some Text</h1>` is not controlled by me. It is on a PHP variable that is generating this code and many more codes/text/data and I cant edit that.

Comment: Well then.. the only left possibility is javascript

Comment: You need help with that javascript or you got that part?

Comment: @InyaProduction Well if you have any awesome code then share with me...

Comment: If you work with jQuery: 
jQuery("#myDiv').html(jQuery(".page-title").html());

Comment: @InyaProduction I have `var content = document.getElementsByClassName("page-title")[0].innerHTML; document.write(content);`...

Comment: Well that should work as its the native style

Comment: @MarvinFischer I was reviewing my questions then I found myself stupid years ago. :) You were right. Now please Answer this question you left in you second comment from top so I will accept it and let others to find an answered question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant execute PHP Script after the page has been loaded at the users browser, do you have all the php script in a variable at php? Then it could be possible to read the value before sending it to the user. Else there is only javascript possible

Answer (score 0):

You need to add id to h1

```
    <h1 class="page-title" id="<?php echo $id;?>">some text</h1>
```

// $id is the id of "sometext" in your table

Comment: Well.. thats not what he is searching for i think